# how to export history tab in snowflake Or is there any metadata view/table i can access current query history?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to export History Page to excel, is there any way i can access current (within 7days ) history?

Note:- please don't tell me to query Snowflake.account_usage.Query_history it has history older than 7 or 15 days. I am looking for current history which needs to be exported to excel.

Comment: Query_history has a latency of up to 45 minutes - I’m not sure where you are getting the 7/15 day figures from? Does waiting 45 minutes not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake account_usage views contain a year's worth of data and have a latency of up to 45 minutes.  If you need something more recent than that, you'd need to use the query_history table functions that leverage information_schema information.  You can find the documentation on those here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html